# Why .iml files should be added to gitignore? What should be placed in gitignore in common case?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Primary question is, why should I add IDEAs *.iml files to gitignore? If then I get repo without .iml file, I will forced to create new project and manualy add my files. Am I wrong about it?

Actualy, my question is slightly wider. Where can I found more information about what should I do for different languages and IDE's. Maybe there are some general rules when creating new repository for first time used language?

Comment: A couple of notes for you: First, you should only ask one question per question. Otherwise, your question is likely "Too Broad" and can be closed as such. Second, concerning _"Where can I found more information"_, requests for off-site resources are off-topic here and are likely to be closed. Please, take some time to look through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site and, for your benefit and to help you get better answers faster in the future, check out the [ask] page for tips to writing good questions.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

> why should I add IDEAs *.iml files to gitignore?

These files get changed all the time when it has nothing to do with the code. If you are not careful you will always be merging this file with every check in with other developers.

> If then I get repo without .iml file, I will forced to create new project and manualy add my files. Am I wrong about it?

Not if you use a build tool like maven, gradle or ant.  These are better options and work outside IntelliJ.

> Where can I found more information about what should I do for different languages and IDE's.

Use Google or if you have a specific question, Stack Overflow.

> Maybe there are some general rules when creating new repository for first time used language?

There are a lot of standards, take your pick.  I suggest you have a look at how projects which are similar to yours have been setup.

Comment: And if I don't use one of the build tools mentioned above, is it acceptably to add .iwl file? Or it will looks like rude tone?

Comment: If you are the only one to use a project you can add .iwl and .iml but if you intend to share the project, use a build tool as these files only work in one IDE.

Comment: Much respect for @Peter Lawrey, but, Jetbrains appears to recommend checking .iml files into version control: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206838875-IntelliJ-files-iml-ipr-etc-and-Source-Control?page=1#community_comment_206318055

Comment: @StvnBrkdll They probably do, but when you have multiple members in a team I found that doesn't work very well. If you have one main author and everyone else just uses the project, I could see it working.

Comment: @StvnBrkdll that link is from 2009, so it made me suspicious that the recommendation may have changed.  Here's a link to an article (updated last week) that does still recommend checking in idea files: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839

Comment: @Brad Johnson: Thanks for the link. However, note that some lines below the recommendation you mention, there is a fat disclaimer, that applies to all Mvn/gradle-managed tools, that de facto reverses the recommendation for most projects:

_"Items you may want to exclude from sharing:

.iml files and .idea/modules.xml file for the Gradle or Maven based projects since these files will be generated on import..."_